# html.dropdownlistfor bind selected value to one column, set another column to the selected Text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm fairly new to mvc and razor views.
I have a DropDownListFor that successfully is populated with a list of values and text from a data table.
I also am successfully binding the selected value to a data column in my data model.
However, the database that I'm working with is not normalized and I have need to taking the Text from the selected item, and binding that to another field in my data model.
How hard is it to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

**1. Call the database to get text after submit**

```
public ActionResult Submit(int dropDownListId) 
{
    var text = string.Empty;
    var dataItem = this._dbContext.SomeTableData.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == dropDownListId);

    if (dataItem != null) 
    {
        text = dataItem.Title;
    }

    // continue
}
```

**2. Adjust the drop down list value and parse the value in controller/business layer:**
If you're using the default DropDownListFor HtmlHelper your data source is type of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so while you're building your Model class you're going to pass it to the view, do something like this:

```
//get data from database
var dataSource = this_dbContext.SomeTableData.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = string.Format("{0}|{1}", m.Id, m.Title),
    Text = m.Title
}
```

And after you submit data parse the value:

```
public ActionResult Submit(string dropDownListValue) {
    string[] values = dropDownListValue.Split('|'); 
    // values[0] = value
    // values[1] = text
}
```

**3.  Add hidden field to the view and use JavaScript to store the text**

```
$('#dropDownListId').on('change', function () {
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $('#dropDownListText').val(text); // hidden field
});
```

and collect the value after submit:

```
public ActionResult Submit(int dropDownListId, string dropDownListText)
{
    //logic
}
```